# Hide a form in a div and show it only after redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, joomla

I have a form which works with a Joomla component which I have modified extensively. Now I want to also add payment integration before the form.
I am planning to hide the application form on the page and then only show it, after successful redirect from Payment. How can I go about this?
The code:
**Application form**

```
<!-- Hide this agent form until page redirect(successful payment) -->
<?php  if($this->agent){ ?>
            <section id="contact-agent">
                <header><h2>APPLY FOR THIS DESIGN</h2></header>
                <div class="row">
                    <section id="contact-agent">
                <header><h2>APPLY FOR THIS DESIGN</h2></header>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="agent-form">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="agent-form">
                            <form role="form" id="form-contact-agent" method="post" action="<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_bt_property"); ?>" class="clearfix">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-contact-agent-name"><?php echo JText::_('COM_BT_PROPERTY_YOUR_NAME');?><em>*</em></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-name" name="name" value="<?php echo $this->user->name; ?>" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-contact-agent-email"><?php echo JText::_('COM_BT_PROPERTY_YOUR_EMAIL');?><em>*</em></label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-email" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->user->email; ?>" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-contact-agent-phone"><?php echo JText::_('COM_BT_PROPERTY_YOUR_PHONE');?><em>*</em></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $this->user->phone; ?>" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-contact-agent-location"><em>Your Current Location*</em></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-location" name="location" value="<?php echo $this->user->location; ?>" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-contact-agent-proposed-location"><em>Proposed Property Location*</em></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-proposed-location" name="proposedlocation" value="<?php echo $this->user->proposedlocation; ?>" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-contact-agent-docs"><em>What documents are you applying for?*</em></label><br/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="ArchitecturalDrawing" value="<?php echo $this->user->ArchitecturalDrawing; ?>" />Architectural Drawing<br/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="StructuralDrawing" value="<?php echo $this->user->StructuralDrawing; ?>" />Structural Drawing<br/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="MechanicalDrawing" value="<?php echo $this->user->MechanicalDrawing; ?>" />Mechanical Drawing<br/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="ElectricalDrawing" value="<?php echo $this->user->ElectricalDrawing; ?>" />Electrical Drawing<br/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="boq" value="<?php echo $this->user->boq; ?>" />Bill of quantities (BOQ)<br/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="construction" value="<?php echo $this->user->construction; ?>" />Construction of building<br/>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <br/>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="terms" value="<?php echo $this->user->terms; ?>" required/>I agree to the Tcs and Cs
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-default" id="form-contact-agent-submit">Apply Now</button>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div id="form-contact-agent-status"></div>

                                <input type="hidden" name="agent_id" value="<?php echo $this->agent->id ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="agent.sendmsg" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->uri->toString(array('path', 'query', 'fragment'))) ?>">
                                <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
                            </form><!-- /#form-contact -->
                        </div><!-- /.agent-form -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-md-5 -->
                </section><!-- /.agent-form -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </section><!-- /#contact-agent -->
```

**Payment Button > Form**

```
<form role="form" id="pay" method="post" action="<https://www.voguepay.com/pay">
<!-- Payment button (hide after successful redirect, show only agent form?) -->
        <div class="pay">
        <input type='hidden' name='v_merchant_id' value='demo' />
<input type='hidden' name='merchant_ref' value='SC-CommitmentFee' />
<input type='hidden' name='memo' value='SC- Design Commitment Fee' />

<input type='hidden' name='developer_code' value='500000d1c' />
<input type='hidden' name='store_id' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='success_url' value='' />
<input type='hidden' name='fail_url' value='' />

<input type='hidden' name='total' value='1500' />
<input type='image' align="right" src='http://voguepay.com/images/buttons/make_payment_green.png' alt='Submit' />   
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The success URL should redirect back to the form with a GET parameter of "payment-success=1", you can then make a condition encapsulating the form:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$paymentSuccess = $jinput->get('payment-success', '0', 'BOOL');
if ($paymentSuccess){
     /* Display the form */
}
```

Comment: what if I want to do the inverse and display the form first and then save the entries, so that on successful payment and redirect from the payment form page, the application form is submitted